# How to continuously communicate to tcp server?

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I have a TCP client which is working at the moment as a terminal. So I can send manually message to the server. But this was just for testing.

BUT I need a continuously communication to the tcp server. I have different fragments to show different data. And in dependancy of the fragments I want send messages. The belonging messages to the fragments are always the same.

Example:

If Fragment 1 is active on GUI: Message1, Answer1, M2, A2, M3, A3, M1, A1, M2, A2...

If Fragment 2 is active on GUI: M5, A5, M6, A6, M7, A7, M5, A5....

So the messages are always repeating and the answer of the server is going to shown on GUI

How can I do that?

Code of the TCP Client:

```
public class Client {

    public static String ServerIP = "192.168.0.10";
    public static int ServerPort = 35000;

    // message to send to the server
    private String mServerMessage;
    // sends message received notifications
    private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;
    // while this is true, the server will continue running
    private boolean mRun = false;
    // used to send messages
    private OutputStream mBufferOut;
    // used to read messages from the server
    private BufferedReader mBufferIn;

    /**
     * Constructor of the class. OnMessagedReceived listens for the messages received from server
     */
    public Client(OnMessageReceived listener) {
        mMessageListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Sends the message entered by client to the server
     *
     * @param message text entered by client
     */
    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        if (mBufferOut != null ) {
            try {
                mBufferOut.write((message + "\r\n").getBytes());
                mBufferOut.flush();
            }   catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Close the connection and release the members
     */
    public void stopClient() {
        Log.i("Debug", "stopClient");

        // send mesage that we are closing the connection
        //sendMessage(Constants.CLOSED_CONNECTION + "Kazy");

        mRun = false;

        if (mBufferOut != null) {
            try {
                mBufferOut.flush();
                mBufferOut.close();
            }   catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        mMessageListener = null;
        mBufferIn = null;
        mBufferOut = null;
        mServerMessage = null;
        Log.i("Debug", "disconnected");
    }

    public void run() {

        mRun = true;

        try {
            //here you must put your computer's IP address.
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(ServerIP);

            Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

            //create a socket to make the connection with the server
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, ServerPort);

            try {
                Log.i("Debug", "inside try catch");
                //sends the message to the server
                mBufferOut = socket.getOutputStream();

                //receives the message which the server sends back
                mBufferIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                MainActivity.ColorBoxHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

                while (mRun) {
                    mServerMessage = mBufferIn.readLine();
                    if (mServerMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                        //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                        mMessageListener.messageReceived(mServerMessage);
                    }

                }
                Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + mServerMessage + "'");

            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);

            } finally {
                //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket
                // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.
                socket.close();
                MainActivity.ColorBoxHandler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);

        }

    }

    //Declare the interface. The method messageReceived(String message) will must be implemented in the MyActivity
    //class at on asynckTask doInBackground
    public interface OnMessageReceived {
        public void messageReceived(String message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you first explain which problems you have now? Why doesnot this code work for you?

Comment: `need a continuously communication to the tcp server.`. Unclear what you mean by that. Do you mean `a permanent connection`?

Comment: This ist just a normal TCP Client. I am programming an OBD2 Car Diagnostic Reader. And my App ist going to connect to an OBD2 Dongle which is plugged in a car. That means I am not sending messages manually. I need a way to send messages automaticly and continuously depending on the active fragment. The fragments show different data, e.g. engine speed or fuel rate... And depending on the fragment there is another message 'routine'

Comment: You have not answered a single question. Only repeated your self. You did not clear up anything. Nor did you make clear what relevance or difference there would be in sending manually or automatically.

Comment: I would like to send the messages in a loop again and again

Comment: Yes. Of course. But what problem do you have doing so? I asked you before to explain your problems. And with 'message' you mean sending a 'command'? Are you able to do so if you had only one fragment?

Comment: Ok know I understand what you mean. I did a while loop with different while loops in it. It works for maybe 2 minutes or sometimes just 1 minute (its random) and then it stops without any error. Message and command is the same in my case. I am trying to develop an app like Torque for car diagnostic because Torque and other similar apps doesn't work with my MCU. It does't mather how many fragments I have, it is always the same. So how I can make that, I don't even need a code. Just some tips for the architecture.

Comment: I have a TCP Client running in his own Thread and another Thread another one with the loop but they are not running very synchronous. I hope could explain a little bit better

Comment: Yes i had hoped that too. But you did not. You told what you have. But i asked you to tell which problems you have to implement the things you want. And you still did not answer all my questions. Please read them again and give to the point answers.